# Postgres: Function that returns composite object comprised of integers as array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqldatatypes

Working with Postgres 11,
So I have a composite data type called bbox which is made of 4 integers (x, y, width, height) in a table called tube_samples.

I want to create a function that returns data from that table alongside data from other tables (using INNER JOINs) but to break that bbox composite type to an array/tuple of integers (I'm using that function from a python API)

This is what I've got working:

```
  create function get_gt_data(clip_name text, OUT tube_id integer, OUT frame integer, OUT bbox bbox, OUT object_type text, OUT done boolean, OUT statis boolean) returns SETOF record
  language SQL as $$
       select S.tube_id, S.frame, S.bbox, B.objecttype, B.done, B.static
       from tube_samples S
            INNER JOIN brief_gt B ON B.tube_id = S.tube_id
            INNER JOIN tubes T  ON B.tube_id = T.tube_id
            INNER JOIN videos V ON V.video_id = T.video_id and V.video_name = clip_name
  $$;
```

The above function returns bbox as a string (example "['1','2','3','4']")
What I want is an integer array to be returned,
Tried changing the return type of bbox to an integer array but couldn't convert that composite data type to an integer array.
The desired outcome should be a tuple/list of integers for that argument e.g [1,2,3,4] instead of the above.

Thanks.

Comment: This function does NOT return bbox as a string, it returns bbox.  Your python wrapper is interpreting it as a string.  Do you want this function to return an array or do you want a tuple or list in python?  If the latter (and you are using psycopg2), register the composite type: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-composite

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, it might not be part of the SQL query but it is good enough.